# Load CSS and JS over HTTPS or HTTP in PMWIKI

Tags: php, css, http, https, pmwiki

We have a website whose home page is http://bigbird.comp.nus.edu.sg/pmwiki/farm/appl/index.php As you see, it is based on `pmwiki`.

We find CSS, JS and other resources are loaded over `http`. That is because links generated by pmwiki's php files are prepended with `http://`. We want to remove the prepended `http://`. Links will become like:

`<script src="//example.com/script.js"></script>`

Which pmwiki's php files should we modify?

Comment: Looks like a pain in the **** but this might help: http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/Cookbook/SwitchToSSLMode-Talk

Comment: The link is helpful.Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Steve finds the right link. Just need to find all urls in `/local/config.php` and modify them as follows:

```
if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == 'on') {
  $FarmPubDirUrl = 'https://www.example.com/~someuser/pmwiki/pub';
} else {
  $FarmPubDirUrl = 'http://www.example.com/~someuser/pmwiki/pub';
}
```

No need to modify the `http://` links in your webpages. I have not done further research. I guess the code means: if the page is requested via `https`, the related url become `https` links.

More detailed explanations are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

According to [PmWiki.PathVariables](http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/PmWiki/PathVariables#FarmPubDirUrl) and [WikiFarms](http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/PmWiki/WikiFarms), the `$FarmPubDirUrl` and the related `$FarmD` variables are the ways PmWiki refers to static content.

Comment: The `$UrlScheme` variable is the PmWiki way prefered way to handle this. You may use the following code:
`$FarmPubDirUrl = $UrlScheme . '://www.example.com/~someuser/pmwiki/pub';`